# Android device orientation , pitch calculation not consistent

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation

I have developing an android application , which requires device inclination for real time processing. the device is inclined on a surface

i wanted to calculate the angle, for this i have used the [project in github](https://github.com/kplatfoot/android-rotation-sensor-sample) to calculate the pitch value. but the pitch values returned by this method is not accurate over multiple tests.. in the pitch value there is some margin of error most of the times .

And the same program tested over another phone it shows different pitch value in same position (laying the phones on the table) .

is there any way i can get the accurate pitch values across multiple devices.

i had used s6 and one plus 2 devices.

Comment: Use SensorListeners directly using `onSensorChanged()`
FYI: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorListener.html

Answer (score 0):

The Rotation Matrix is defined by applying roll first, then the pitch, and finally the yaw rotation. You can get the phone in the same position if you apply pitch first, then roll and again finally yaw. This is why you expect a certain pitch, but you get inaccurate values.

To prove to yourself this, play with the phone by bringing it in a certain random position by applying angle rotations in an certain order and then try to get to the same position by different order of rotations (a good position to try is phone in vertical position like keeping it in front of your face and tilted a bit to the side).

Most of the times you would use code like this

```
int rotation = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
if(rotation == 0) // Default display rotation is portrait
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(Rmat, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, R2);
else   // Default display rotation is landscape
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(Rmat, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, R2);
```

to make it more intuitive. This is how by you *virtually* would change the order, since you still have the Rotation Matrix defined by applying roll first, then the pitch, and finally the yaw rotation, but however this rotations are defined against an new XYZ coordinate system.

> public abstract void onSensorChanged (int sensor, float[] values)
>   Added in API level 1
>
> Called when sensor values have changed. The length and contents of the values array vary depending on which sensor is being monitored. See SensorManager for details on possible sensor types.
>
> Definition of the coordinate system used below.
>
> The X axis refers to the screen's horizontal axis (the small edge in portrait mode, the long edge in landscape mode) and points to the right.
>
> The Y axis refers to the screen's vertical axis and points towards the top of the screen (the origin is in the lower-left corner).
>
> The Z axis points toward the sky when the device is lying on its back on a table.
>
> IMPORTANT NOTE: The axis are swapped when the device's screen orientation changes. To access the unswapped values, use indices 3, 4 and 5 in values[].
>
> SENSOR_ORIENTATION, SENSOR_ORIENTATION_RAW:
>
> All values are angles in degrees.
>
> values[0]: Azimuth, rotation around the Z axis (0<=azimuth<360). 0 = North, 90 = East, 180 = South, 270 = West
>
> values[1]: Pitch, rotation around X axis (-180<=pitch<=180), with positive values when the z-axis moves toward the y-axis.
>
> values[2]: Roll, rotation around Y axis (-90<=roll<=90), with positive values when the z-axis moves toward the x-axis.
>
> Note that this definition of yaw, pitch and roll is different from the traditional definition used in aviation where the X axis is along the long side of the plane (tail to nose).

And the difference between phones it is expected.